# Gluster/Lustre like for Windows?

Tags: file, system, distributed

Are there any opensource projects that are similar to gluster/lustre for windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gluster supports Samba so you can have Gluster servers running on Linux and easily serve Windows clients.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about Openfiler but never tried it myself, more info available at its website and wiki gives a decent overview:

http://www.openfiler.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfiler